# Receiving the error Code: SubscriptionNotFound Message: The subscription not found when trying to get data about Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I am working on a script that accesses details about an Azure Virtual Machine currently. This is the code that I have so far:

```
"""
    Instantiate the ComputeManagementClient with the appropriate credentials.

    @return ComputeManagementClient object
"""
def get_access_to_virtual_machine():
    subscription_id = key.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential(authority = AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_GOVERNMENT, 
                                        exclude_environment_credential = True,
                                        exclude_managed_identity_credential = True,
                                        exclude_shared_token_cache_credential = True)
    client = KeyClient(vault_url = key.VAULT_URL, credential = credentials)                     
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    return compute_client

"""
    Check to see if Azure Virtual Machine exists and the state of the virtual machine.
"""
def get_azure_vm(resource_group_name, virtual_machine_name):
    compute_client = get_access_to_virtual_machine()
    vm_data = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name, 
                                                virtual_machine_name, 
                                                expand = 'instanceView')
    return vm_data
```

When trying to run `get_azure_vm(key.RESOURCE_GROUP, key.VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME)` which I am certain does have the correct credentials, I get the following error output (note that I replaced the actual subscription ID with 'xxxx' for now):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shilpakancharla/Documents/function_app/WeedsMediaUploadTrigger/event_process.py", line 62, in <module>
    vm_data = get_azure_vm(key.RESOURCE_GROUP, key.VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME)
  File "<decorator-gen-2>", line 2, in get_azure_vm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/retry/api.py", line 73, in retry_decorator
    return __retry_internal(partial(f, *args, **kwargs), exceptions, tries, delay, max_delay, backoff, jitter,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/retry/api.py", line 33, in __retry_internal
    return f()
  File "/Users/shilpakancharla/Documents/function_app/WeedsMediaUploadTrigger/event_process.py", line 55, in get_azure_vm
    vm_data = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name, 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/mgmt/compute/v2019_12_01/operations/_virtual_machines_operations.py", line 641, in get
    map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/exceptions.py", line 102, in map_error
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (SubscriptionNotFound) The subscription 'xxxx' could not be found.
Code: SubscriptionNotFound
Message: The subscription 'xxxx' could not be found.
```

I am using the beta preview version of `azure.mgmt.compute` which was installed with `pip install azure-mgmt-compute=17.0.0b1`. Note that I am also using an Azure Government account. Is there a way to solve this error? I have also tried using `ServicePrincipalCredentials` and `get_azure_credentials()` but ran into different errors - I was recommended to use `DefaultAzureCredentials` and the key vault by a coworker.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the code and it works fine on my side. And the error message shows the reason:

> azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (SubscriptionNotFound)
> The subscription 'xxxx' could not be found. Code: SubscriptionNotFound
> Message: The subscription 'xxxx' could not be found.

It seems you run the python code in your local machine. I recommend you log in with the Azure CLI first and then check if the subscription id that you used in your python code is right.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is valid and the subscription id is correct, then the next check would be to see whether the service provider 'Microsoft.Storage' is registered at the subscription level or not.

The below cli command(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/provider?view=azure-cli-latest#az-provider-register) tells you how to register a service provider.

**syntax:**

```
az provider register --namespace
                     [--consent-to-permissions]
                     [--management-group-id]
                     [--wait]
```

**example:**

```
az provider register -n Microsoft.Storage --subscription <subscription-id>
```

After this, your automation code should be able to make calls to storage related APIs.